# What is the definition for the dot product of a co-vector and a dyadic product of vectors?

Tags: tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors

The definition of the dot product of a second order tensor with a vector is:
$$ (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}) \cdotp \mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{b} \cdotp \mathbf{x})\mathbf{a} $$
The definition of the dot product of a third order tensor with a vector is:
$$ (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} \otimes \mathbf{c}) \cdotp \mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{c} \cdotp \mathbf{x}) (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}) $$
Is it the case that:
$$ \mathbf{x}^T \cdotp (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}) =(\mathbf{x}^T \cdotp \mathbf{a}^T)\mathbf{b}^T$$
I believe the transpose on $\mathbf{a}$ is needed because the dot product must be either between two vectors or two co-vectors. I also believe the transpose on $\mathbf{b}$ is needed to make the shape of the resulting vector come out right.  Like in matrix multiplications where a row vector times a matrix gives a row vector.  But I'm not sure whether $\mathbf{x}^T \cdotp (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b})$ even makes sense conceptually or if only makes sense to write $\mathbf{x}^T \cdotp (\mathbf{a}^T \otimes \mathbf{b}^T)$?

Is it the case that:

$$ \mathbf{x}^T \cdotp (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} \otimes \mathbf{c}) = (\mathbf{c} \cdotp \mathbf{x}) (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b})^T = (\mathbf{c} \cdotp \mathbf{x}) (\mathbf{a}^T \otimes \mathbf{b}^T) $$

Comment: If you write $\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b}$ as the matrix product $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^\top$ (column vector $\mathbf{a}$ times row vector $\mathbf{b}^\top$) all those things should become fairly clear.

Comment: Using [index notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) your last case is simply
$$ x_i\,(a_ib_jc_k) = (x_ia_i)\,b_jc_k \qquad \qquad \qquad
$$
Written in matrix notation this becomes
$$ \def\k{\otimes} 
x\cdot(a\k b\k c) = (x\cdot a)\;b\k c \;\equiv\; (x^Ta)\;bc^T
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a long comment rather than an answer.

Take your first definition,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b}) \cdot \pmb{x}= (\pmb{b} \cdot \pmb{x}) \pmb{a}
$$
This only makes sense if, somehow,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b}) \cdot \pmb{x} = 
(a^i \pmb{e}_i \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j}) x^k \pmb{x}_k 
= a^i \pmb{e}_i (b_jx^j) 
$$
i.e., as if by magic, $\pmb{b}$ is a covector (in Euclidean space you could call this $\pmb{b}^T$ but then you would simply write
$\pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\pmb{x}$ as @Kurt G. suggested). Then if we write $(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b}) \cdot \pmb{x}^T$ using the same
definitions,
$$
(a^i \pmb{e}_i \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j}) x_k \pmb{x}^k = (a^ix_i) \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j}
$$
or $(\pmb{x}^T\pmb{a}) \pmb{b}^T$.

Your second definition is even more difficult to decipher. You write,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b} \otimes \pmb{c}) \cdot \pmb{x}= (\pmb{c} \cdot \pmb{x}) \pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b}
$$
so $\pmb{c}$ is also a covector and we have,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b} \otimes \pmb{c}) \cdot \pmb{x} = 
(a^i \pmb{e}_i \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j} \otimes c_k \pmb{e^k}) x^l \pmb{e}_l =
(c_k x^k)  (a^i \pmb{e}_i \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j})
$$
Then,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b} \otimes \pmb{c}) \cdot \pmb{x}^T = 
(a^i \pmb{e}_i \otimes b_j \pmb{e^j} \otimes c_k \pmb{e^k}) x_l \pmb{e}^l =
(c_k a^k)  (b_j \pmb{e^j} \otimes c_k \pmb{e^k})
$$
i.e. using your notation,
$$
(\pmb{a} \otimes \pmb{b} \otimes \pmb{c}) \cdot \pmb{x}^T =
(\pmb{a} \cdot \pmb{x}) (\pmb{b} \otimes \pmb{c})
$$